# How do I Create Tablespace in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle

I am not too savvy in Oracle, and I have been trying to create a TABLESPACE, which keep on giving me an error message of invalid file name. Below is the syntax that I have used:

```
SQL> create Tablespace HRMT
2 datafile
3 size
4 ;
size
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02236: invalid file name
```

My book and all websites that I have been to suggest that I specify the file path for the DATAFILE, and when I specify a path, I get another error message.

```
SQL> create tablespace vania
2 datafile 'home/oracle/hait/'
3 size 10M
4 ;
create tablespace vania
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'home/oracle/hait/'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Do I need to create the datafile first before I can create the TABLESPACE? Are there pre-existing datafiles in the database that I can use? What would be the proper syntax to create a tablespace and/or a datafile? How and where do I create a .dbf file to create the tablespace?

Comment: Voting for migration to ServerFault, because this is about administration of a database.

Comment: I know it's a very very late answer, but what do you suppose that database administrators do? :-)

Answer (score 28):

The answer to your question can be found in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm) (excerpt follows).

> **Creating Basic Tablespaces: Examples**
>
> This statement creates a tablespace
>   named tbs_01 with one data file:
>
> `CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_01 DATAFILE 'tbs_f2.dbf' SIZE 40M     ONLINE;`

It sound like you are new to Oracle databases.  Oracle provides a wealth of documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/en/database.  Specifically, I recommend reading their excellent introduction to the database called the [Concepts Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

Obviously, if you want a datafile, you have to give it a name:

```
SQL> create tablespace vania
2 datafile '/home/oracle/hait/vania01.dbf'
3 size 10M
4 ;
```

There are [loads of examples](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/create_tablespace.html) of this if you do [a very simple search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=oracle%20create%20tablespace&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-24).

Comment: rtfg eh? hey I will search that....

Comment: Just google it with Bing...

Answer (score 8):

For this kind of very basic questions like
"How to create a tablespace in Oracle?"
I would strongly recommend the very good [Online Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/index.htm).

In the particular case, you get from there to Oracle® Database Administrator's Guide
11g Release 2 (11.2) - [Creating Tablespaces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tspaces.htm#ADMIN11359)

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE <tablespace_name>
  DATAFILE 'datafile_name.dbf'
  SIZE 20M AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

where 20M is size of your datafile.
AutoExtend On => size is automatically extended as the datafile is filled.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure that your datafile folder exists. On UNIX do the following:

```
ls /home/oracle/hait  #if you get an error here, it means you need to create the folder first

mkdir -p /home/oracle/hait
```

Finally, if you are in Oracle 11g where tablespace management is purely local, you can 
do the following:

```
create tablespace vania datafile '/home/oracle/hait/vania01.dbf' size 10M;
```

This will not work in Oracle 7 or 8i; you have to clearly specify how your extents are going to be managed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> create tablespace vania
2 datafile 'D:/home/oracle/hait/vania01.dbf'
3 size 10M
4 ;
```

Comment: Could you explain on this a little further?

Answer (score 1):

```
create tablespace MY_TB
datafile 'D:\app\Administrator\oradata\MYORA\MY_TB.dbf'
uniform size 33K
max size unlimited
extend management local
segmentspace management manual
auto extend on next 40K
disable logging
/
```